# Speed: four ints or one int with many operations

Tags: java, performance, variables, int, bit-manipulation

I have a speed question for Java. I am making a chess program, and I want to check if is a good idea to use one `int` as a variable to store four `int` variables, in which the values range from 1 to 4 bits.

The problem is that I'll often have to extract and put in new parts of the variable, so that will cost quite some bitwise operations.

Code:

```
int fromX = 4, fromY = 5, toX = 6, toY = 7;
int move = 0
move |= toY;
move = move << 4;
move |= toX;
move = move << 4;
move |= fromY;
move = move << 4;
move |= fromX;

doWork(move);
```

or

```
int fromX = 4, fromY = 5, toX = 6, toY = 7;
doWork(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
```

`doWork()` will do a lot of different things with the coordinates, mostly extract them from the 'int', or just use the variables.

Which should I use?

Comment: There is no "unsigned" in java.

Comment: I suppose he means "an int where I ignore the sign-bit".

Comment: You're right, I just mean 'int'...

Comment: I guess the question is whether passing 4 arguments incurs a speed penalty over passing 1 argument.  I'm inclined to think that the cost of packing your 4 variables into one and then unpacking on the other side would be less efficient than whatever Java does with 4 arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to check if is a good idea to use one 'unsigned int' as a variable to store four 'int' variables

No, this is a *Bad Idea*™ for a bunch of reasons.

1. This would be highly inefficient
2. Very hard to *read*
3. (consequently) very hard to *debug*

Sure, it may save a few bytes here and there, but honestly, I buy my RAM-modules in gigabytes these days.

**My suggestion:**

Write up your entire chess-program. *If* you run into performance problems, *profile* the program to see where the bottle-necks are, and do something about those. (I can guarantee you that you won't start packing several numbers into an `int` once you reach this point.)

Comment: I have written most of my program, and I don't want to write very big parts of it again. That's why I asked. I'll start profiling in some days, when I finish a major bug. Thanks!

Comment: Very good answer. I agree with each word. I just want to add that the question is the classical example of premature optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store some Flags, you can use BitSet for example.
If it is data, I second aioobe's answer.

Comment: I really don't want to make any Objects, because anything I do will be reapeated about 10 million times, when searching in my chess-game-possible-move-tree... And the coordinates are not really flags, they change a lot, and are passed back and forth beween methods.

Comment: OK, I see. Then you might want to think about creating a "Context" or "Arguments" - Object once and share that one instance over your 10 gazillion calls ...

Answer (score 0):

As Alan Kay [said](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKayQuotes),

> "Make it work, make it correct, make it fast, make it cheap"

Once you've got the program working, measure it to find out what's slow, or what takes too much space. You can then make a reasoned decision about what you need to optimise.